# Finding Galois extension isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: galois-theory

Exist a method to find an Galois extension $E$ such that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Only for $n=6$ how can I do?

Comment: For $n=6$, let $E$ be the cyclotomic field of the $7$th root of unity.

Comment: If you're referring to the integers modulo n, you should write it as $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$. This notation emphasizes key properties of the group and  avoids confusion with the $n$-adic integers.

Comment: @Batominovski, for $n=3$, if $E$ is the cyclotomic field of the $4$th root of unity then $E$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. You have some idea how to find $E$ n this case?

Comment: I haven't thought about the general situation.  But if $n+1$ is a prime number, then $\text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{n+1}\right)/\mathbb{Q}\big)\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$, where $\zeta_k:=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi \text{i}}{k}\right)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You also have $\text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{p^r}\right)/\mathbb{Q}\big)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{r-1}(p-1)}\cong \text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{2p^r}\right)/\mathbb{Q}\big)$ for all prime integers $p>2$ and for any $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Batominovski you know a paper with this demonstration?

Comment: Well, it is just a number-theoretical problem with a bit of Galois theory.  First, show that $\text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_n\right)/\mathbb{Q}\big)\cong \text{Units}\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)$, where $\text{Units}(R)$ is the group of units of a unital ring $R$.  Then, prove that $\text{Units}\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)$ is cyclic if and only if $n=1,2,4,p^r,2p^r$ where $p>2$ is a prime integer and $r\in\mathbb{N}$, in which case $\text{Units}\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: For the number-theoretical part, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n.

Comment: @Batominovski OK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find $m$ such that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_m^{\ast}$ has a quotient group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. You can do this by letting $m$ be a prime congruent to $1 \bmod n$. By Galois theory, the fixed field of the kernel of the corresponding quotient is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

(Furthermore, the [Kronecker-Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem) asserts that all such Galois extensions arise in this way.)

For example, for $n = 3$ you can take $m = 7$. The relevant subgroup of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ is generated by complex conjugation $\zeta_7 \mapsto \zeta_7^{-1}$, and its fixed subfield is $\mathbb{Q} \left( \cos \frac{2\pi}{7} \right)$.